# How to store a comment's depth in PRAW?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I would like to be able to iterate over comments in a post up to level `n`, and record each comment along with its depth. I see no way to readily do this in Praw, though.

I wanna do something like this:

```py
def get_post_comments(post, comment_limit):
  comments = []
  post.comments.replace_more(limit=comment_limit)
  for comment in post.comments.list():
    # do something 

  return [comment.body, comment_depth]
```

But I am unsure how to get a comment's depth.

Answer (score 1):

You use `post.comments.list()`, which the PRAW documentation explains [returns a flattened list of the comments](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/other/commentforest.html#praw.models.comment_forest.CommentForest.list). For your purposes, since you care about depth, you don't want a flat list! You want the original un-flattened `CommentForest`.

Using recursion, we can visit comments in this forest with a depth-first traversal using a generator:

```
def process_comment(comment, depth=0):
    """Generate comment bodies and depths."""
    yield comment.body, depth
    for reply in comment.replies:
        yield from process_comment(reply, depth + 1)

def get_post_comments(post, more_limit=32):
    """Get a list of (body, depth) pairs for the comments in the post."""
    comments = []
    post.comments.replace_more(limit=more_limit)
    for top_level in post.comments:
        comments.extend(process_comment(top_level))
    return comments
```

Alternatively, you can perform a breadth-first traversal without recursion (we could also do the depth-first without recursion, using a stack explicitly) as the [PRAW documentation explains](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/comments.html) — see the section starting with "However, the comment forest can be arbitrarily deep…".